# How to update multiple rows in a table?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update

I have to update the table `daytot` with the values present in the array named `$result3`.

How could this be done?

```
$this->db->select('tdate');
$this->db->where('tdate >=', $newDate);
$this->db->where('tdate <=', $date);
$result3=$this->db->get('daytot')->result_array();
$amount=$this->input->post('credit1');
for($i=0;$i<count($result3);$i++) {
    $opcash=$result3[$i]['opcash']+$amount;
    $data1 = array(
        'tdate'=>$newDate,
        'total_credit'=>$total_credit['amount'],
        'total_debit'=>$total_debit['amount'],
        'opcash'=>$opcash,
    ;
    $this->db->where('tdate', $result3[$i]);
    $this->db->update('daytot', $data1);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do u want? Do u want to avoid the loop?

Comment: i have more than one value in $result3 and i want to update opcash value to the values(dates) present in a $result3array

Comment: What a result of the code? What is not working?

Comment: i want to update opcash to all the date which is present in $result3  array

Comment: Now, is `opcash` updating or not?

Comment: @laavanyadharani what is result of `$result3` array?

Comment: @DanishAli nope.. opcash is not updating

Comment: Try like this $opcash=$result3['opcash']+$amount;

Comment: $result3 array have the tdate values..that is opcash needed to be updated for the $result3 array values

Comment: Add `$result3` array structure in your question.

Comment: i can't use like that because i have more than one index..so i am using for loop

Comment: @laavanyadharani what line, what offset?

Comment: Use `foreach` loop.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["tdate"]=> string(10) "24/12/2018" } } array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["tdate"]=> string(10) "25/12/2018" } } $result3 array value

Comment: I am getting undefined offset in $this->db->where('tdate', $result3[$i]); line@splash58

Comment: Array does not have 'opcash'.

Comment: Yes..i have opcash value in $data1 array

Comment: In this line of code $opcash=$result3[$i]['opcash']+$amount;  have issue. Because offset 'opcash' does not exists

Comment: added opcash to the $result3 array still having the same issue

Comment: Now this is the structure?
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["tdate"]=> string(10) "24/12/2018", ["opcash"] => string(10) 'value'} } array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["tdate"]=> string(10) "25/12/2018", , ["opcash"] => string(10) 'value' } } $result3

Comment: yes..{ ["tdate"]=> string(10) "24/12/2018" ["opcash"]=> string(3) "500" } { ["tdate"]=> string(10) "25/12/2018" ["opcash"]=> string(3) "1000" }

Comment: look at the answer that I've provided

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `foreach` loop for update the record

`$result3` array structure is

```
{ ["tdate"]=> string(10) "24/12/2018" ["opcash"]=> string(3) "500" } { ["tdate"]=> string(10) "25/12/2018" ["opcash"]=> string(3) "1000" }
```

So try like this. And make sure you have all the variable values

```
$this->db->select('tdate');
$this->db->where('tdate >=', $newDate);
$this->db->where('tdate <=', $date);
$result3=$this->db->get('daytot')->result_array();
$amount=$this->input->post('credit1');
```

Now check if `$result3` have record or not

```
if(isset($result3) && count($result3) > 0){
foreach($result3 as $result) {
    $opcash=$result['opcash']+$amount;
    $data1 = array(
    'tdate'=>$newDate,
    'total_credit'=>$total_credit['amount'],
    'total_debit'=>$total_debit['amount'],
    'opcash'=>$opcash,
   ;
    $this->db->where('tdate', $result['tdate']);
   $this->db->update('daytot', $data1);
}
}
```

Comment: I want opcash to be updated fo be update for all the date present in $resul3 array

Comment: not working..i have to update the opcash value to all the date that is presnt in $result3 array

Comment: did you understand my problem??

Comment: @laavanyadharani yes.

Comment: getting undefined index opcash and tdate

Answer (score 0):

Try below method. `id` is a unique value from the table `daytot`, you can use any unique field.

```
$this->db->select('id, tdate, opcash'); //id => primary key
$this->db->where('tdate >=', $newDate);
$this->db->where('tdate <=', $date);
$result3 = $this->db->get('daytot')->result_array();
$amount  = $this->input->post('credit1');
```

Using For

```
$data1 = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result3); $i++) {
    $opcash = $result3[$i]['opcash'] + $amount;
    $data1[]  = array(
        'id'        => $result3[$i]['id'],
        'tdate'        => $newDate,
        'total_credit' => $total_credit['amount'],
        'total_debit'  => $total_debit['amount'],
        'opcash'       => $opcash
    );    
}
$this->db->update_batch('daytot', $data1, 'id');
```

OR Using Foreach

```
foreach($result3 as &$data){
    $opcash = $data['opcash'] + $amount;
    $data['tdate'] = $newDate;
    $data['total_credit'] = $total_credit['amount'];
    $data['total_debit'] = $total_debit['amount'];
    $data['opcash'] = $opcash;    
}
$this->db->update_batch('daytot', $result3, 'id');
```

Comment: why for loop will not work, could you explain it please? because I couldn't find any issue.

Comment: @KarthikSekar getting undefined index tdate

Comment: i have to update the opcash value where tdate present in $result3 array

Comment: error message: Undefined index: tdate UPDATE `daytot` SET `tdate` = CASE WHEN `tdate` = THEN '24/12/2018' ELSE `tdate` END, `total_credit` = CASE WHEN `tdate` = THEN '2500' ELSE `total_credit` END, `total_debit` = CASE WHEN `tdate` = THEN NULL ELSE `total_debit` END, `opcash` = CASE WHEN `tdate` = THEN 1000 ELSE `opcash` END WHERE `tdate` IN()

Comment: looks like tdate field is empty in your table. print array before execute update_batch

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["tdate"]=> string(10) "24/12/2018" ["opcash"]=> string(3) "500" } } Array ( [0] => Array ( [tdate] => 24/12/2018 [total_credit] => 3500 [total_debit] => [opcash] => 1000 ) )this is my data1 value

Comment: print the complete array before update_batch, like based on my code if you use for print_r($data1), if you use foreach print_r($result3)

Comment: yes done like this rray(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["tdate"]=> string(10) "24/12/2018" ["opcash"]=> string(3) "500" } [1]=> array(2) { ["tdate"]=> string(10) "25/12/2018" ["opcash"]=> string(4) "1000" } } data1 value..but getting undefined index tdate

Comment: Let me check in my local

Comment: @laavanyadharani, I am able to update, please refer my screenshots https://prnt.sc/m0kbma  https://prnt.sc/m0kcad

Comment: $data1 = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result3); $i++) {
    $opcash = $result3[$i]['opcash'] + $amount;
    $data1[]  = array(
        'tdate'        => $result3[$i]['tdate'],
        'total_credit' => $total_credit['amount'],
        'total_debit'  => $total_debit['amount'],
        'opcash'       => $opcash
    );    
} i have changed my data1 like this

Comment: @KarthikSekar still getting undefined index tdate

Comment: I think your update_batch data variable is wrong, yours should be $this->db->update_batch('daytot', $data1, 'tdate');

Comment: yes used like this..now getting Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/Finance/system/database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 1898 error

Comment: sorry..I don't have skype

Comment: can i connect you through teamviewer or anydesk??

Comment: lets discuss here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185953/how-to-update-the-multiple-rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185957/discussion-between-laavanya-dharani-and-karthik-sekar).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to select `opcash` column too :

```
$this->db->select('tdate,opcash');
```

Then apply an index `0` on each `foreach` iteration :

```
if(isset($result3) && count($result3) > 0){
    foreach($result3 as $r) {
        $opcash=$r[0]['opcash']+$amount;
        $data1 = array(
            'tdate'=>$newDate,
            'total_credit'=>$total_credit['amount'],
            'total_debit'=>$total_debit['amount'],
            'opcash'=>$opcash,
        );
        $this->db->where('tdate', $r[0]['tdate']);
        $this->db->update('daytot', $data1);
    }
}
```

Comment: getting undefined offset 1

Comment: `undefined offset 1` at what line?

Comment: $opcash=$r[0]['opcash']+$amount;$this->db->where('tdate', $r[0]['tdate']);in both the lines

Comment: what happen if you remove the `[0]` on each line?

Comment: invalid argument suppplied for foreach

Comment: not the `0` on `foreach` line, but on `$r[0]` line... change all `$r[0]` to `$r` and what is the output?